# Is a binomial expansion of the denominator valid here?

Tags: limits, contour-integration, binomial-theorem

I am trying to prove this integral tends towards zero (a variation of the Hankel contour problem). I am not sure if my approximation is valid here,

My integral round a circular pole at the origin is, 
$$
   I_{2}
   =
   \int_{2 \pi}^0
   \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{u} -1}
   du
$$
I make a substitution, $u = \epsilon e^{i\theta}$ to get,
$$
   I_{2}=
   \int_{2\pi}^{0}
   \frac
    {\left(\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)^{s-1}}
    {e^{\epsilon e^{i\theta}} - 1}
   d(\epsilon e^{i\theta})
$$
Here is the bit where I think I'm being a bit dodgy: In the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$, I take a binomial expansion of the denominator to get,
$$
   I_{2}=
   \int_{2\pi}^{0}
   \left(\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)^{s-1}
   \left(1 + e^{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}\right)
   d(\epsilon e^{i\theta})
$$
        Then for $\text{Re}(s>1)$, $I_2 \to 0$ as 
        $\epsilon \to 0$ since the integrand is proportional to $\epsilon^{s}$.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: This is not valid because $e^{0}$ is not small.

The actual solution cam to me whilst thinking about it. By considering the integral of

Firstly consider,
$$
 e^{u} > e^{u} - 1
$$
so,
$$
\int \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{u}} du \gt \int \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{u} - 1} du
$$
Now expanding the LHS integrand in a power series, we get,
$$
\int u^s \left( \frac{1}{u} - 1 +\mathcal{O}(u)\right) du
$$
and  $u \propto \epsilon$, so as long as $Re(s) > 1$ then $\text{LHS} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ and therefore $I_2 \to 0$ because of the inequality relationship.